# How to delete based on select query

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to delete the rows of that are the result of this query

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b 
  ON a.id = b.id 
WHERE b.id IS NULL;
```

How to do it?

I have tried:

```sql
DELETE  
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b 
  ON a.id = b.id 
WHERE b.id IS NULL;
```

But it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Use `not exists`:

```
delete a from a
    where not exists (select 1 from b where b.id = a.id);
```